# Oracle SQL; Determine if value is unique or not in a group

Tags: sql, oracle, unique

Im struggeling and till today have not found a solution.
I need to determine if the product group is mixed or unique.

Criteria :

> 1. If all SKU's in Pallet have product group LAMINAAT -> LAM
> 2. If all SKU's in Pallet have product group ACCESSORIE -> ACC
> 3. If it is a mix of LAMINAAT and ACCESSORIE -> MIX
> 4. As soon as 1 SKU has a product group ≠ LAMINAAT or ACCESSORIE -> Leave this field blank

the result of my current select statement gives the below result:

```
ORDER_ID,    PALLET_ID,              SKU_ID,    PRODUCT_GROUP
80081876    00257084646912345679    9410-3798   ACCESSORIE
80081876    00257084646912345679    9420-3012   ACCESSORIE
80081876    00257084646912345679    9410-3012   ACCESSORIE
80081876    00257084646912345679    9410-3010   ACCESSORIE
80081876    00257084646912345678    9420-3865   ACCESSORIE
80081876    00257084646912345678    9410-3857   ACCESSORIE
80081876    00257084646912345678    9420-3010   ACCESSORIE
80081876    00997084646920000197    3010-3798   LAMINAAT
80081876    00280120160000000001    9420-3853   ACCESSORIE
80081876    00280120160000000001    9420-3895   ACCESSORIE
80081876    00280120160000000001    9320-3853   LAMINAAT
80081876    00280120160000000001    9420-3798   ACCESSORIE
```

The result set of data should say:

```
Pallet id                    product group
00257084646912345679          ACC
00280120160000000001          MIX 
00997084646920000197          LAM
```

I was thinking of this code

```
WITH  cte AS
(SELECT pallet_id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT PRODUCT_GROUP) AS counter
FROM product_group_data
GROUP BY pallet_id
)
SELECT p.pallet_id,
        p.PRODUCT_GROUP, 
        CASE WHEN c.counter = 1 
              THEN SUBSTR(p.PRODUCT_GROUP,1,3) 
              ELSE 'MIX' 
        END uniq
FROM product_group_data p
JOIN cte c
  ON p.pallet_id = c.pallet_id
```

This covers 1,2,3 of the criteria.. sadly not the 4.

Any ideas are more then welcome

thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. What would be your exact desired result? A field added to your current search result with the LAM/ACC/MIX type added for each row, or just a grouping with the pallet id and a type?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear questions..

Yes I want to have a result that says: 
order :80081876   
pallet: 00257084646912345679    
Productgroup:  ACC 

Or if the pallet contains a laminaar and accessorie : mixed

Comment: You're saying a different thing in your question (which the answer below solves), order_id isn't included there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to assign new labels based on the members of the product_group

```
select pallet_id,
    case 
        when count(case when product_group not in ('LAMINAAT','ACCESSORIE') then 1 end) > 0 then ''
        when count(distinct product_group) > 1 then 'Mix'
        when count(case when product_group = 'LAMINAAT' then 1 end) > 0 then 'LAM'
        else 'ACC'
    end as label
from mytable
group by pallet_id
```

Comment: That nailed it FuzzyTree :) 

I had already a wrapped up a code but this is leaner and more efficient :)

Thanks

Comment: @Marty210578 glad it helped